# getting started with intern (javascript testing) on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, testing, intern

```
I can't seem to get started with Javascript testing using intern.

After installing the software via following the instructions, I'm still getting errors when I try to run sample tests using the default configuration with 1 minor change -- I use the NullTunnel instead of the SauceLabsTunnel.  Can someone help me get past this problem?

I did the following...
1) downloaded and installed npm and node on a windows 7 system.
2) executed the line 'npm install intern' on the command line.
3) copied the tests directory and example.intern.js file (from within node_modules/intern) to a directory named throwaway.
4) renamed the 'example.intern.js' to 'intern.js'
4.5) edited the intern.js file and changed 'tunnel' from 'SuaceLabsTunnel' to 'NullTunnel'.
5) downloaded the file 'selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar'
6) executed the file with the command line 'java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar'
7) on a different command line, executed the following '\node_modules\.bin\intern-runner.cmd config=intern.js'
8) got the output...

Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
TypeError: Object # has no method 'relative'
    at getSource (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:191:22)
    at formatLine (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:230:40)
    at processChromeTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:242:16)
    at normalizeStackTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:293:38)
    at Object.getErrorMessage (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:396:14)
    at Object.logError (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:432:23)
    at Object./error (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/runner.js:41:9)
    at Object.target.(anonymous function).dispatcher [as on/error] (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modul
es/intern/node_modules/dojo/aspect.js:91:38)
    at Function.on.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/on.js:281:37)
    at Object.Evented.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Evented.js:3
1:19)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred
.js:84:15)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:55:5)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:84:15
)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:58:4)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\dojo\Promise.js:
256:37
    at runCallbacks (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\do
jo\Promise.js:13:18)
    ----------------------------------------
[object Deferred]
    at Promise.then.promise.then (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferr
ed.js:252:24)
    at Suite.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:312:7)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:54:18
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:325:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:53:16)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/runner.js:275:12
    at execModule (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:515:54)
    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:582:7
    at guardCheckComplete (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:566:4
)
TypeError: Object # has no method 'relative'
    at getSource (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:191:22)
    at formatLine (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:230:40)
    at processChromeTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:242:16)
    at normalizeStackTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:293:38)
    at Object.getErrorMessage (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:396:14)
    at Object.logError (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:432:23)
    at Object./error (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/runner.js:41:9)
    at Object.target.(anonymous function).dispatcher [as on/error] (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modul
es/intern/node_modules/dojo/aspect.js:91:38)
    at Function.on.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/on.js:281:37)
    at Object.Evented.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Evented.js:3
1:19)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred
.js:84:15)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:55:5)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:84:15
)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:58:4)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\dojo\Promise.js:
256:37
    at runCallbacks (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\do
jo\Promise.js:13:18)
    ----------------------------------------
[object Deferred]
    at Promise.then.promise.then (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferr
ed.js:252:24)
    at Suite.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:312:7)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:54:18
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:325:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:53:16)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/runner.js:275:12
    at execModule (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:515:54)
    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:582:7
    at guardCheckComplete (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:566:4
)
TypeError: Object # has no method 'relative'
    at getSource (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:191:22)
    at formatLine (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:230:40)
    at processChromeTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:242:16)
    at normalizeStackTrace (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:293:38)
    at Object.getErrorMessage (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:396:14)
    at Object.logError (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:432:23)
    at Object./error (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/reporters/runner.js:41:9)
    at Object.target.(anonymous function).dispatcher [as on/error] (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modul
es/intern/node_modules/dojo/aspect.js:91:38)
    at Function.on.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/on.js:281:37)
    at Object.Evented.emit (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Evented.js:3
1:19)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred
.js:84:15)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:55:5)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at signalDeferred (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:84:15
)
    at signalListener (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:58:4)

    at signalWaiting (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:28:4)
    at reject.reject (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:219:5)

    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\dojo\Promise.js:
256:37
    at runCallbacks (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\leadfoot\node_modules\do
jo\Promise.js:13:18)
    ----------------------------------------
[object Deferred]
    at Promise.then.promise.then (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferr
ed.js:252:24)
    at Suite.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:312:7)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:54:18
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/lib/util.js:325:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.run (C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/main.js:53:16)
    at C:/Users/someuser/workspace/web/throwaway/node_modules/intern/runner.js:275:12
    at execModule (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:515:54)
    at C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:582:7
    at guardCheckComplete (C:\Users\someuser\workspace\web\throwaway\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:566:4
)
```

Comment: "get me started" is not a very specific question.  Can you ask a more specific question?  What exactly do you need help with.  Where exactly are you stuck?  Also, can you do anything to properly format your question - it's a visual mess to try to read.  You can't generally use StackOverflow to get a tutorial on how to get started on something.  It works better for specific questions like: "I did x, y and z and I was trying to accomplish Q, but got stuck on P.  I tried a, b and c to figure it out, but can't figure out why it won't get past P".

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very sepcific question, but I believe the error lies in your configuration file. Make sure you have the following lines:

```
// Name of the tunnel class to use for WebDriver tests
tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

// Whether or not to start Sauce Connect before running tests
useSauceConnect: false,

webdriver: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
}
```

I would really urge you to sign up for a fee saucelabs trial and get the intern example working properly before attempting to use your own selenium server. You will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately updating the intern.js file did not help with the recommendations above did not work.  

I'm trying to make intern the testing platform for Javascript at the company I work for.  I need to prove that it works locally before migrating to a Saucelabs server.

Comment: I understand that you need to get it working locally, but you should get it working *at all* before you begin trying to make things more complex by testing locally. The Intern example uses saucelabs and should work out-of-the-box without changing any settings (given you provide saucelabs info - E.G. Free trial). After you can get the example working properly, then try to make changes and run locally. This will remove any doubt about external issues (system/path problems, etc.). If you can't get the example working then you are going to have a difficult time getting a full test suite running.